# loading data from json in sencha

Tags: json, sencha-touch

I am creating an application where i have created a list and populated the data in the list using a data store.

data.js

```
Ext.regModel('Contact', {
             fields: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'DOB', 'group']
             });

iPolis.ListStore = new Ext.data.Store({
                    model: 'Contact',
                    sorters: 'lastName',
                    getGroupString : function(record) {
                                    return record.get('group');
                    },
                    data: [
                           { firstName: "Domino",      lastName: "Derval" , DOB: "28May2008", group:"Personalize"},

                           ]
                    });
```

This part of the code runs fine where i get the data and display it. Now what i require is a connection to the database and retriving the data in the data.js using a json file.

Any suggestions on how thats possible?

```
iPolis.ListStore = new Ext.data.Store({
     model : 'Contact',
     proxy : {
         type : 'ajax',
         url : 'js/person_list.json',
         reader : {
             type : 'json',
             //root : 'results',
             // totalCount : 'total'
         }
     },
     autoLoad : true
});
```

used this for getting the data but it gives me an error sayin XMLHttprequest cannot load data in file.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through the Ext.data.Proxy in Sencha API and also check the [examples](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) of store in API docs.

Comment: I did. iPolis.ListStore = new Ext.data.Store({
   model : 'Contact',
   proxy : {
     type : 'ajax',
     url : 'js/person_list.json',
     reader : {
       type : 'json',
       //root : 'results',
      // totalCount : 'total'
     }
   },
   autoLoad : true
 }); used this for getting the data but it gives me an error sayin XMLHttprequest cannot load data in file.json.

Comment: Check the json file location and also the proper format in jsonlint.com

Answer (score -1):

1. Just replace the url property of reader to the php file.
2. return proper JSON